# svn: E175002: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans

I installed netbeans on my ubuntu 12.04 system to use for php programming from the netbeans website.

While taking the check out from the svn repository i am geting the error

```
svn: E175002: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
```

I checked for the issue and came up with this

```
http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-176
```

but I could not found eclipse.ini in my netbeans installation.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22070546-deploy-fails-with-received-fatal-alert-bad-record-mac

Answer (score 5):

```
1. Add the following line to the eclipse.ini file in your eclipse installation directory.
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3  
2. Restart eclipse.
3. Repeat the same operation as before and it should complete without any errrors.
```

Comment: +1 This solution works correctly on Eclipse. However, the question was concerning Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

i also experienced this in Netbeans, previously the svn working normally then suddenly  having error like bad_record_mac

i can solve this problem by restarting Netbeans then the svn working again.